# Applescript Check if file exists in network, path with variable

Tags: path, applescript

I am trying to check if a file exists in a folder that is on the network.
When I hardcode the path as in the second example, the script works as excpected

However on the first example, the script does not work correctly. I believe that I quote my variable correctly separating the strings and variables with "" and & and also making sure that the final variable is converted to string.

```
  tell application "Finder"
    set a to "video1"
    set thefile to ("/Volumes/folder/" & a & ".avi")
    if exists POSIX file (thefile as string) then
        log "True"
    else
        log "False"
    end if
end tell

tell application "Finder"
    if exists POSIX file ("/Volumes/folder/video1.avi") then
        log "True"
    else
        log "False"
    end if
end tell
```

Is there a way to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

There is a more convenient way.

The Finder treats both local and network volumes as `disk`. The name of the disk is the path component after `Volumes`.

However I recommend to prefer `System Events` which is more optimized and has also a `disk` element.

```
set a to "video1"
set thefile to a & ".avi"
tell application "System Events"
   if exists file thefile of disk "folder" then
      log "True"
   else
      log "False"
   end if
end tell
```